# Go wrap httprouter to have logger?

Tags: google-app-engine, http, logging, go

I have the following `httprouter` handler but I want to customize so that I can inject my own logger functions.

```
router := httprouter.New()
router.Handle("GET", "/mysite", mylogger(handler1))
```

And `mylogger` is like:

```
var logger = log.New(os.Stdout, "[Log] ", 0)
func mylogger(fn func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, param httprouter.Params)) func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, param httprouter.Params) {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, param httprouter.Params) {
        start := time.Now()
        logger.Printf("%s %s", r.Method, r.URL.Path)
        fn(w, r, param)
        logger.Printf("Done in %v (%s %s)", time.Since(start), r.Method, r.URL.Path)
    }
}
```

And `myhandler` is like:

```
func myhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    ....
}
```

Is there any way that I can wrap the `httprouter` handler that I do not have to pass handler to `mylogger` function? I want to do something like in Go AppEngine Context:

```
func AppEngineHandler(c appengine.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
  ...
  c.Infof("Here's my log")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having used the `httprouter` package before, it would appear all you need to do is change the function signature you're attempting to wrap.

So, firstly, change the declaration of the `fn` argument in the method:

```
func mylogger(fn func(c *myapp.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, param httprouter.Params))
//                    ^^^^^ have it accept a context of your own
```

..then create and pass the context into your handler in the wrapper:

```
c := &myapp.Context{ your: arguments, here: true }
fn(c, w, r, param)
// ^^ - pass the context in
```

Then change the signature of your handler:

```
func myhandler(c *myapp.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    // use c here
}
```